# Cannot create CDK stack for AWS S3 Glacier in CDK app?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cdk

I decided to use [AWS S3 Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/glacier/) for data archiving. All of IaC was written by using CDK apps (TypeScript). That's why I decided to create a new CDK app and define `S3GlacierStack`. As far as I understood, [StorageClass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.StorageClass.html) is the most appropriate way to do it. As you can see, it supports TypeScript. So I decided to create a simple CDK app and try to create S3 bucket by using the code example from [AWS CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3.StorageClass.html). Unfortunately, I faced the following error when I run `cdk list` command: `Error: Cannot use 'noncurrent' rules on a nonversioned bucket`. What did I do wrong? What is the recommended approach to use AWS S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval storage class in CDK apps? Here is the code of my CDK app.

**cdk-app-1.ts**

```
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { S3GlacierStack } from '../lib/s3-glacier-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
new S3GlacierStack(app, 'S3GlacierStack', {});
```

**s3-glacier-stack.ts**

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as s3 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3";
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class S3GlacierStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {

    super(scope, id, props);

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 's3-glacier', {
      lifecycleRules: [{
        abortIncompleteMultipartUploadAfter: cdk.Duration.minutes(30),
        enabled: false,
        expiration: cdk.Duration.days(30),
        expirationDate: new Date(),
        expiredObjectDeleteMarker: false,
        id: 's3-glacier',
        noncurrentVersionExpiration: cdk.Duration.days(30),
        // the properties below are optional
        noncurrentVersionsToRetain: 123,
        noncurrentVersionTransitions: [{
          storageClass: s3.StorageClass.GLACIER,
          transitionAfter: cdk.Duration.days(30),
          // the properties below are optional
          noncurrentVersionsToRetain: 123,
        }],
        objectSizeGreaterThan: 500,
        prefix: 'prefix',
        objectSizeLessThan: 10000,
        transitions: [{
          storageClass: s3.StorageClass.GLACIER,
          // the properties below are optional
          transitionAfter: cdk.Duration.days(30),
          transitionDate: new Date(),
        }],
      }]
    });
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "cdk-app-1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "cdk-app-1": "bin/cdk-app-1.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "aws-cdk": "2.50.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.50.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

This is the error I see in my terminal when I run `cdk list` command.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable object [versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html) on your Bucket with `versioned: true`.

The CDK error message is telling you that your noncurrent rule (what to do with previous object versions) makes no sense if bucket versioning isn't enabled.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to resolve the issue.